# Scipy Least Squares 2 squares desired // Error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares, minimize

Current I'm attempting to use scipy's least squares, or any of their minimization functions to minimize a function with 5 parameters.

What I would like scipy to do is minimize some function using a standard least squares.

My code is below:

```
 fitfunc1 = lambda p, xx, yy, zz: -(50000*(xx + (p[0] + p[1])*yy +  
 p[3]))/(1.67*(-p[2]*yy + zz + p[4]))

 errfunc1 = lambda p,x11, xx, yy, zz: fitfunc1(p, xx, yy, zz) - x11
 x0 = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], dtype = float)

res3 = leastsq(errfunc1, x0[:], args=(x1, x, y, z))
```

where x1, x, y, z are all column numpy arrays of the same length about 90x1

I'm currently getting an error that says ' Error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats', I've attempted many possibilities, and tried to rewrite this the way it is described in examples, but doesn't seem to work.

In addition: I actually would like to solve the problem:

min sum (f - x1)**2 + (g - x2)**2 
where f = f(p, x, y, z) and g = g(p, x, y, z) and x, y, z, x1, y1 are all data, but attempting to find the parameters, p (6 of them).

Is this currently possible in least squares? I have attempted using scipy.minimize, but when this is done using the Nedler's Mead method, it doesn't seem to work either.

Here is my current code:

```
def f(phi, psi, theta, xnot, ynot, znot):
  return sum(abs(   (-50000*(x[:]+ (psi + phi)*y[:] + xnot)/(1.67*(-
   theta*y[:] + z[:] + znot))) - x1[:]) //
  + abs(   (-50000*(-x[:]*(psi + phi) + y[:] + theta*(z[:]) + ynot)/(1.67*(-
  theta*y[:] + z[:] + znot))) - y1[:]))

  x0 = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], dtype = float)
  res3 = leastsq(f, x0[:], args=(x1, y1, x, y, z))
```

I feel as if I am making some mistake that may be obvious to someone more familiar, but this is my first time using scipy.  All help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is with the shape of the variables:

> where x1, x, y, z are all column numpy arrays of the same length about 90x1

It causes your `fitfunc1` and `errfunc1` functions to return 2d arrays (of shape (90,1)), where the scipy optimization function expects a 1d array.
Try reshaping your arrays, e.g.,

`x1 = x1.reshape((90,))`,

and similarly for the rest of your input variables.
This should fix your problem.